# Dockerizing a Play application - downloading the internet

Tags: java, docker, playframework

I am trying to dockerize a Java application which I used to deploy earlier on a server directly. Basically we had a copy of the repo on the server and ran these two steps for deplopyment (after we updated the repo):

```
./bin/activator clean stage
./target/universal/stage/bin/app-server -J-Xms128M -J-Xmx512m -J-server -Dconfig.resource=application.conf
```

When I was dockerizing the application, I basically did this :

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN mkdir home/app-server
ENV HOME=home/app-server

COPY . $HOME

WORKDIR $HOME

RUN ./bin/activator clean stage  #this is inside the $HOME directory

EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["./target/universal/stage/bin/app-server", "-J-Xms128M", "-J-Xmx512m", "-J-server", "-Dhttp.port=5000", "-Dconfig.resource=stage.conf"]
```

But the `./bin/activator clean stage` pretty much downloads the internet:

```
Getting com.typesafe.activator activator-launcher 1.3.12 ...
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.activator/activator-launcher/1.3.12/jars/activator-launcher.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.activator#activator-launcher;1.3.12!activator-launcher.jar (1460ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.8/scala-library-2.11.8.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.11.8!scala-library.jar (310ms)
```

To get by this I created a base image which I agree is a mess (hashed together from various blogs / SO posts):

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV JAVA_HOME       /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
ENV LANG            en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL          en_US.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends locales unzip && \
  locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 && \
  apt-get dist-upgrade -y && \
  apt-get --purge remove openjdk* && \
  echo "oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true" | debconf-set-selections && \
  echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java-trusty.list && \
  apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EEA14886 && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends oracle-java8-installer oracle-java8-set-default && \
  apt-get clean all

RUN apt-get install -y curl && \
    curl -OL https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.2.0/protoc-3.2.0-linux-x86_64.zip && \
    unzip protoc-3.2.0-linux-x86_64.zip -d protoc3 && \
    mv protoc3/bin/* /usr/local/bin/ && \
    mv protoc3/include/* /usr/local/include/

RUN wget http://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/1.3.2/typesafe-activator-1.3.2-minimal.zip && \
    unzip typesafe-activator-1.3.2-minimal.zip && \
    mv activator-1.3.2-minimal /bin/activator
```

However even when I use the base image the `/bin/activator clean stage` step downloads all the jars again. While the whole process works , it takes about 20 mins for a docker image to be built which is very slow.

How can I speed up or improve the time taken to build by app image ?

Answer (score 3):

From your cli output i guess you are using version 2.3 of Play Framework. The commands shown can be different in other versions.

You are building your app completely in your new docker container. Since an empty image does not contain any dependencies, it has to download them all.

A better option is to build a standalone version of your application ([Play Framwork Documentation: Creating a standalone version of your application](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionDist)) on your development machine - where all dependencies are already downloaded - via

```sh
activator dist
```

or

```sh
activator universal:package-zip-tarball
```

Those commands produce a `.zip` or `.tgz` file of your application with all dependencies bundled.

Then you can copy them into your Docker container, unzip them and start your application without having to download all dependencies.

If you use the `.tgz` packaging you can copy **and** unpack the archive into your docker container by using

```
ADD app-server.tgs $HOME
```

in your Dockerfile.